# Suppress whitespace

Tags: pdftex

For the sake of readable code, I like to separate e.g. a textblock from some equation environment, using blank lines. Unfortunately, this produces different output in the .pdf. 
Is there a way to suppress this behaviour? Note: Using Overleaf with pdfLatex as a compiler. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

This is some dummy text \begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

And supposely this is a bigger gap:

\begin{equation}
    2+2 = 4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: First of `standalone` is probably not the right tool for an example like this as it make several special choices. As Niklas mentions you have no blank like (= new paragraph) in the first example, and a blank like in the other. Simple solution: remove the unnecessary blank lines (or start them with `%` so they are ignored). A blank like indicate a new paragraph and 99% of the time one never starts a new paragraph with a displayed formula.

Comment: @daleif This is exactly the point. Is there a way to supress the behavior to interpret a blank line as a new paragraph? What kind of donkey language has blank lines with a syntax (looking angrily at python)?

Comment: You should not remove the paragraph indentation. It is there for a reason. Say your document is printed. Without paragraph indentation how does the reader know when a new paragraph starts? It is easy to come up with many examples where the user has to try to interpret the text in order to figure out if there is a newparagraph or not. With the paragraph indentation, the is no ambiguity.

Comment: I don't mind the indentation. I mind loss of control of wether I want the indentation or not. Assigning blank line syntax ruins the readability of the .tex.

Comment: Not understood. The blank line as a marker of a new paragraph is a part of the TeX syntax. What we are saying is that you have too many. There should not be a blank line over the last displayed formula.

Comment: Thank you @daleif . I will not argue with Knuth. All hail Knuth. It seems % is the way to go.

Comment: you ask what languages use blank lines as syntax: _lots_ of document oriented languages do that, including the markdown used on this site which similarly interprets a blank line as code to end a paragarph. TeX syntax is optimised for writing the document which makes coding seem odd at times, just the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a new line in the second equation but not the first one. This makes a new paragraph, therefore adding white space.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

This is some dummy text 
\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

And supposely this is a bigger gap:
\begin{equation}
    2+2 = 4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, never suggest users to use ``\\`` in the text, it is always wrong. The user should not be inserting blank lines in the first place.

Comment: @daleif Never heard about that, why is it bad to use? `\break` I assume is okey to use?

Comment: Users should never insert manual line breaks in the text. They should write paragraphs separated by blank lines. ``\\`` is fine when appropriate (tables, matrices, align etc), but has no place used in the text. In my LaTeX book I make an effurt to never mention that ``\\`` can be used in the text as users (at the time) has a tendency to use it everywhere. Use paragraphs, and embrace the fact that paragraphs are indented (they are for a reason).

Comment: note that the  extra visible space is not vertical space to tex (and for example not dropped at a page break) it is a spurious 1-line paragraph with no visible text.

Comment: The example as shown *does not* have a blank line (paragraph break) before the second equation.  What's it supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am talking about his code not mine, I made the two texts and equations equal.